# Corda - Does Finality flow ends before states were recorded in all participants vaults?

Tags: corda

Recently I came across a problem when it seems that when the flow ends on initiator's node, and immediately after that I query the output state of the transaction in vaults of all transaction participant nodes, it turns out that the state is present only on initiator's node, and only after a while it appears in vaults of other participants nodes.
Reading the documentations [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/api-flows.html) "Send the transaction to the counterparty for recording", and it does not say that it will wait until counterparty will successfully record the transaction and its states to their vault, which sort of confirms that the issue that I am facing is actually the way Corda is implemented and not a bug or so.

On the other hand, it seems not that logical to end a flow without being sure that on the counterparty node everything was finished successfully and all the states are written in their vaults.

And also I looked into the code, and reached to this method in `ServiceHubInternal`, which seems to be responsible for recording states into vault.

```
fun recordTransactions(statesToRecord: StatesToRecord,
                           txs: Collection<SignedTransaction>,
                           validatedTransactions: WritableTransactionStorage,
                           stateMachineRecordedTransactionMapping: StateMachineRecordedTransactionMappingStorage,
                           vaultService: VaultServiceInternal,
                           database: CordaPersistence) {

        database.transaction {
            require(txs.isNotEmpty()) { "No transactions passed in for recording" }

            val orderedTxs = topologicalSort(txs)
            val (recordedTransactions, previouslySeenTxs) = if (statesToRecord != StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE) {
                orderedTxs.filter(validatedTransactions::addTransaction) to emptyList()
            } else {
                orderedTxs.partition(validatedTransactions::addTransaction)
            }
            val stateMachineRunId = FlowStateMachineImpl.currentStateMachine()?.id
            if (stateMachineRunId != null) {
                recordedTransactions.forEach {
                    stateMachineRecordedTransactionMapping.addMapping(stateMachineRunId, it.id)
                }
            } else {
                log.warn("Transactions recorded from outside of a state machine")
            }

            vaultService.notifyAll(statesToRecord, recordedTransactions.map { it.coreTransaction }, previouslySeenTxs.map { it.coreTransaction })
        }
    }
```

And it does not seem to me that this method is doing something async, so I am really confused.
And so the actual question is:

**Does Initiator flow in Corda actually waits until all the relevant states are recorded in vaults of all participant nodes before it finishes, or it finishes right after it sends the states to participant nodes for recording without waiting for a confirmation from their side that states were recorded?**

**Edited**

So in case that Corda by default does not wait for counterparty flows to store states in their vaults, but my implementation needs this behavior anyways, would it be good solution to implement the following:

At the very end of Initiator flow, before returning from method call [receiveAll](https://api.corda.net/api/corda-enterprise/4.3.1/html/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.testing.flows/receive-all.html) in order to suspend and wait, then in the very end of the receiver flow, before returning from method do a vault query with `trackBy` to wait until the state of an interest is recorded in the vault, and whenever it is, call `sendAll` to notify the initiator's `receiveAll` method. And finish the initiator's flow only when it has received confirmation from all receivers..

Would it be a normal approach to solve this problem? can it have any drawbacks or side effects that you can think of?

Answer (score 2):

Corda is able to handle your scenario, it is actually explained [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/api-flows.html) under the `Error handling behaviour` section; below is an excerpt, but I recommend reading the full section:

> To recover from this scenario, the receiver’s finality handler will automatically be sent to the Flow Hospital where it’s suspended and retried from its last checkpoint upon node restart

Answer (score 1):

The Initiator flow is not responsible for the storage of the states in the Responder's vault. So, there is no storage confirmation from the Responder, since it has already checked the transaction and provided signatures. So, from the Initiator's point of view it's all good once the Transaction has been notarised and stored on its side, it is up to the Responder to manage errors in its storage phase, as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Thank you very much Alessandro. I edited my question with a solution to my problem that I think can solve it for me, can you please have a look?